# gzip: stdin: not in gzip format

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, gzip, gitlab-omnibus

I am  building chef-server from source on ubuntu. when I run the commend

```
bin/omnibus build chef-server
```

This is the error message I get

```
The following shell command exited with status 1:

$ CFLAGS=-I/opt/opscode/embedded/include \
-O2 CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/opscode/embedded/include \
-O2 CXXFLAGS=-I/opt/opscode/embedded/include \
-O2 LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,/opt/opscode/embedded/lib \
-L/opt/opscode/embedded/lib \
LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/opscode/embedded/lib \
PATH=/opt/opscode/bin:\
/opt/opscode/embedded/bin:\
/root/.gem/ruby/bin:\
/App-cpanminus-1.7040/bin:\
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:\
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin \
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/pkgconfig \
cat cpanm | \
perl - App::cpanminus
```

Output:

```
--> Working on App::cpanminus
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7040.tar.gz ... OK
```

Error:

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
/bin/tar: Child returned status 1
/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
! Failed to unpack App-cpanminus-1.7040.tar.gz: no directory
! Failed to fetch distribution App-cpanminus-1.7040
```

Comment: did you check that all the files were correctly downloaded? I will start there by double checking the sha/checksum of every file